# Size and position of triangle div element to its parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a child div that is a colored triangle:

```
 .shape-triangle {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 25px solid transparent;
     border-right: 25px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 50px solid green;
     /* put on top of image */
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     left: 110px;
}
```

that is nested inside a Bootstrap column with a background image:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="shape-triangle"></div>
    <img src="assets/background.png" alt="Image">
</div>
```

It sits on top of a background image (a bunch of grayscale shapes):

[image: original]

When my screen/browser window is reduced in size, the image resizes but the triangle obviously doesn't:

[image: reduced-size]

How do I get the colored triangle to remain proportional in size and position to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rescale th div with the screen size or its parent, you need to use the unit `%` for the `.shape-triangle`. Unit `px` will never work, because it keeps that size, while the parent `.col-12` is changing. For the borders you need the unit `rem`, which will relate the size to the root font.

So my suggestion will be something like this (you will have to play around with the `%` and `rem` to see what is the best).

```
.shape-triangle {
     border-left: 2.5rem solid transparent;
     border-right: 2.5rem solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 5rem solid green;
     /* keep on its position and size */
     position: absolute;
     top: 20%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
}
```